# Is this Hibernate Idiom thread safe?

Tags: java, hibernate

**The problem**

I need to ensure that when a group of entities are modified on Thread-A, their changes are updated in unison on Thread-B. The changes also must not be blocking Thread-A, so the objects are detached. No changes are made to an Entity on Thread-A when Thread-B is updating them.

**Question**

What is the best solution to this problem? If not, what is? Is this Idiom safe? If so, why?

**Code**

**Step 1** (Thread A): Create object and store in collection

```java
Collection<MyEntity> collection = ...;

MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();

entity.setValue(1);

collection.add(entity);
```

**Step 2** (Thread B): Persist object created on Thread A then detach

```java
Session session = ...; // assume initialized

Transaction transaction = ...; // assume initialized

transaction.being();

session.persist(entity);

transaction.commit();

session.detach(entity);
```

**Step 3** (Thread-A): After updating, allow the object to be modified on Thread-A.

**Step 4** (Thread-B): After more changes are made, update on Thread-B.

Comment: Instead of thinking about whether this is threadsafe or not please think about what you are actually trying to achieve and elaborate on that. That "modify the entity in thread A and persist the changes in thread B"-stuff seems quite weird and error prone.

Comment: In my opinion, enough information is provided to answer whether or not this solution is viable.

Comment: Well, with the information provided I'd say that solution is not viable. Why? Because we don't know how you'd want to ensure that there won't be any concurrent modifications and what those threads are actually doing and how they are coordinated. To me this feels like a [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) but if you think there's enough information and your general aproach is sound then go ahead and try it.

Comment: This could definitely be considered a question about a solution rather than a problem, but it's the idiom i'm asking about, not my implementation. The question is whether this idiom is safe and viable.

In regards to ensuring no concurrent modifications, the object is only modifiable if some internal (possibly transient) state is set to the value required to modify.

Comment: Well, that idiom _can_ be safe if implemented correctly and it _might_ be viable but without knowing more about the problem. It feels overly complicated and I'd say you need really good reasons to make a pattern such as this viable.